# Finding the last 2 digits of a perfect number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

I want to find the last two digits of the perfect number $2^{126}(2^{127}-1)$. I know that in order to do this we want to work modulo $100$:

$$2^{126}(2^{127}-1)\ (mod 100)$$

But it doesn't seem as though Fermat's little theorem or Euler's theorem are any use. Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Consider $\mod 4$ and $\mod 25$ individually, then apply Chinese Remainder Theorem (CRT)

Comment: @GarethMa This is what I have so far - let $x=2^{126}(2^{127}-1)$. Then clearly $x\equiv 0(mod 4)$. For modulo $25$, are we allowed to say that $2^{125}\equiv 2^0(mod 25)\equiv 1(mod 25)$? Or is that an erroneous claim? IF it is correct then $x\equiv 2(2^1-1)\equiv 6(mod 25)$. Then we can use CRT to find the answer

Comment: No, $2^{125}\not\equiv 2^0\mod 25$. Review the statement of Euler's Theorem :)

Comment: @paw88789 My bad, deleted

Comment: If you want to verify your answer, I have the first 15 perfect numbers (& Mersenne primes) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40631767/4014959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$x=2^{126}(2^{127}-1)$$  we wish to calculate last two digits of $x$

since $4|x $ now we will try out to find $\; x\mod25$

using *Euler's therorem* $x\equiv 2^{6}(2^7-1) \mod25\equiv (-2^3-2^6) \mod25$

$x\equiv-22\mod25\equiv 3\mod25$

since $4|x\Rightarrow \exists \;k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=4k$ now $4k\equiv 3\mod 25$

$$k=3\times 4^{-1}\mod 25\equiv 7 \mod 25$$

Now $x=4(25q+7)=100q+28$

Hence last two digits are *28*

Comment: Thanks - this is excellent! How did you get the result on the line where you say "Using Euler's theorem..." though? It doesn't seem to be an immediate corollary

Comment: From group in multiplication modulo $n$ $U(n)=\{1\leq x<n :\; \gcd(x,n)=1\}$ Now $\phi(n)$ is order of the group by defination . We can say any $x\in U(n)$ we have $x^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\mod n$

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{126}(2^{127}-1)=2^{253}-2^{126}$$

The remainder is periodic for mod 100:

$2^3\equiv 8\bmod 100$

$2^{13}\equiv 92\bmod 100$

$2^{23}\equiv 8\bmod 100$

$2^{33}\equiv 92\bmod 100$

$2^{43}\equiv 8\bmod 100$

$2^{53}\equiv 92\bmod 100$

$2^{253}=2^{53}\times 2^{200}$

$2^{10}\equiv 24\bmod 100$

$2^{20}=(2^{10})^{20}\equiv 24^{20}\bmod 100$

$24^5=7962624\equiv 24\bmod 100$

$2^{20}=(24^5)^4=7962624\equiv 24^4\equiv 76\bmod 100$

$2^{200}=(2^{20})^{10}\equiv 76^{10}\equiv 76\bmod 100$

$2^{253}\equiv 92\times 76=692\equiv 92\bmod 100$

$2^{126}=(2^{53})^2\times 2^{20}\equiv (92)^2\times 76\equiv 64\bmod 100$

Finally:

$2^{253}-2^{126}\equiv (92-64=28)\bmod 100$